# How can I do what was once called 'git subtree pull-all' today?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I see some references that there was initially a "git subtree pull-all" functionality in git subtree (before it was merged into the main git branch). Like http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/22061209807/apps-i-love-git-subtree

What I'd need is a quick way to fetch subtrees (and the subtrees of subtrees, recursively...) present in the current repo. What is the advised way of doing this today?
  push-all would also be handy.
  I wouldn't want to use submodules.

Thanks!